# Put a key named metaClass in a Map

Tags: groovy, dictionary, metaclass

I've written a [small Groovy script](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/290001) that exposes a very weird behaviour. can anyone explain it ?

```
// Creating a groovy map 
def map = [:] 
// Putting a value in 
map["a"]="b"
// Render it without trouble 
println map["a"] 
// Putting another value in (yup, this one has THE name) 
map["metaClass"]="c"
// Failing to render it 
println map["metaClass"]
```

My question in that case is quite simple : why does the last instruction will throw the exception below :

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'c' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'groovy.lang.MetaClass'
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:8)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
map["metaClass"]="c"
```

is the same as writing:

```
map.metaClass = "c"
```

I am guessing that before it delegates to the `Map.put(x,y)` method, it checks to see if a `setXxxx` method exists on the object.

As there is a method (in every object in Groovy) called `setMetaClass()`, it then calls this method instead of setting the property in the map (and fails to cast `"c"` to a metaClass object, as you have seen)

Workarounds:

- Don't have a key called `metaClass`
- Use `map.put( 'metaClass', 'c' )` instead of the groovy magic